# How to fix the arc and angle of this DLWidgetMenu library

Tags: objective-c, github, menu, core-animation

I would like to implement DLWMRadialMenuViewController class in my project from library https://github.com/regexident/DLWidgetMenu and fixed the following but its not working and after run the app its look like radial circle. Can anyone help me to implement this library.

```
self.items = 5;
self.radius = 59.0; // in pixels
self.arc = 200; // in radians
self.angle = 168; // in radians
self.minDistance = 45.0; // in pixels
self.uniformOuterLayer = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment says `in radians` but you are providing values that look like degrees. To convert from degrees to radians:

```
self.arc = 200 * M_PI / 180.0;
self.angle = 168 * M_PI / 180.0;
```